# Connecting to mysql database returns (mysqli) object fulla' null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am connecting to a localhost database, and for this I created a class that goes as such:

```
<?php

class Database
{
    private $host, $user, $pass, $db;

    /**
     * @var mysqli
     */
    private $link;

    public function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db)
    {
        $this->host = $host; $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass; $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        if ($this->link->connect_errno > 0) die("Cannot connect to server.");
    }

    public function getLink()
    {
        return $this->link;
    }

    public function reconnect($host, $user, $pass, $db)
    {
        $this->host = $host; $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pass; $this->db = $db;
        $this->connect();
    }
}
```

And I connect to it as such:

```
$database = new Database("localhost", "username", "password", "dbname");
$database->connect();
$mysqli = $database->getLink();
```

But when I `var_dump` the mysqli variable, all it gives me is a full list of null's, as such:

```
object(mysqli)[2]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'client_info' => null
      public 'client_version' => null
      public 'connect_errno' => null
      public 'connect_error' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'host_info' => null
      public 'info' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'server_info' => null
      public 'server_version' => null
      public 'stat' => null
      public 'sqlstate' => null
      public 'protocol_version' => null
      public 'thread_id' => null
      public 'warning_count' => null
```

Why is this happening? I haven't done anything different from the many times I have done this before...

**EDIT**

`var_dump` of `$database`:

```
object(Database)[1]
  private 'host' => string 'localhost' (length=9)
  private 'user' => string 'username' (length=4)
  private 'pass' => string 'password' (length=0)
  private 'db' => string 'dbname' (length=2)
  private 'link' =>
    object(mysqli)[2]
      public 'affected_rows' => null
      public 'client_info' => null
      public 'client_version' => null
      public 'connect_errno' => null
      public 'connect_error' => null
      public 'errno' => null
      public 'error' => null
      public 'error_list' => null
      public 'field_count' => null
      public 'host_info' => null
      public 'info' => null
      public 'insert_id' => null
      public 'server_info' => null
      public 'server_version' => null
      public 'stat' => null
      public 'sqlstate' => null
      public 'protocol_version' => null
      public 'thread_id' => null
      public 'warning_count' => null
```

- Restarting Apache and MySQL did not work to resolve issue

Comment: what you are getting for `var_dump($database);` ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, added var dump of object as edit

Comment: @AlankarMore, where do I use `mysql_*` functionality? it is purely OOP `mysqli`...

Comment: You need to add return value to your `connect` function as  `return $this->link;`

Comment: @Saty, as you can see in the `var_dump` of `$database`, doing this would not help matters, it (rightly) makes a mysqli object, but everything is null so I cannot do anything with it. A return value in the `connect` function wouldnt do anything

Comment: @AlankarMore, also, you forgot about `mysqli`, an OOP framework for databasing, it is a valid and non deprecated option for database work. Also it is what I am using and what I am going to stick to

Comment: @SamSwift웃 I have executed your code and its working as expected. $database = new Database("localhost", "root", "", "test");
$database->connect();
$mysqli = $database->getLink();
$res = $mysqli->query('select * from tmp');
$result = $res->fetch_assoc();
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Okay thanks for information. As you are getting all values `null` so because of this are not you able to execute the queries against your mentioned database?

Comment: @AlankarMore, I am not, anything I try to do against the DB does not work

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Might be you are having any different issue. I agree with  Sanjeev kumar your code is working fine at my end too.

Comment: @SamSwift웃 i have also same issue looks like you... 
i'm creating class for configuration and for queries, query class create new configuration object and new mysqli connection object, alway get null if try to get object connection from sub class, success in supper class(class queries), and success in single file (without class), mariadb and php are in separate server....
any one have answer..?